display custom form for res.partner subclass when clicking partner internal link
Using Odoo 17, I've subclassed res.partner with delegation inheritance, and created a custom form view for the subclass.
class MyPartnerExt(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.partner.ext'
    _inherits = {'res.partner': 'partner_id'}

    ext_field = fields.Integer()

I would like to display the custom form whenever the internal link for the partner is clicked, and the record is an instance of the subclass.

So lets say the My delegate​ partner above is an instance of MyPartnerExt, I would like to display the custom form. Otherwise it should display the standard form.
Is this possible? Thanks in advance.
(ps. I've experimented with inheriting the form and adding/removing fields, but this gets too complicated for my actual requirements. https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/custom-view-based-on-res-partner-subclass-254782)
